# How to write a PCRE regular expression pattern in Amazon s3 SDK for PHP in get_object_list method

Tags: php, regex, amazon-s3

I am using the [Amazon S3 SDK for PHP](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/get_object_list) and trying to write a regular expression to search for a sub directory within a path that is dynamic.  I understand that the Amazon S3 does not have "sub directories" like a typical file system, but from my understanding the get_object_list method allows for a pcre option to find a string in an object on S3.  By using the pcre option I am hoping to be able to find a sub directory within a path.

For example.

```
$find_directory = "foo";
$reg_ex = "/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/";

$response = $s3->get_object_list(MY_BUCKET, array(
        'pcre' => some/path/" . $reg_ex . "/" . $find_directory . "/",
        'max-keys' => 1
));

if ( (count($response)) > 0){echo "yes it exists";}else{echo "no it does not exist";}
```

I would expect that it would find any directory path that has:

```
some/path/(any directory with letters, numbers, or underscores)/foo
```

But this regular expression is not working, or the way I am formatting the pcre is not correct.

I am getting the warning:

> preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric
>   or backslash in sdk-1.5.2/utilities/array.class.php on line 114

What is the proper way to write this regular expression within the pcre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the opening double quote in the `some/path"`.

You should also use a delimiter that is not found in the result. Change `/` to `#` or something. Hope it helps, I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The double quote should be there, but after putting it in it does not change the resulting warning.

Comment: How about the changing of the delimiter in `$reg_ex`? I realized `/` is not in the reg ex pattern, but in the whole response. You could also change `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` simply to `[\w]` but that shouldn't have any affect to error message.

Comment: I think I found the issue.  It appears that if I escape the / to \/ and adding / the the beginning and the end, then it will work. I will continue to test this.

Comment: Yes, that would be the delimiter issue I was trying to clarify. It's unclear to me if you want to match `/sometext/` or `sometext`. In PHP's reg ex function you must have delimiter so the following should work if you want to match also ´/´ alonside with ´sometext´. ´$reg_ex = "#/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/#";´ Also ´$reg_ex = "/\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\//";´ should work fine but it's good idea to use delimiters not present in the reg ex pattern. (Straight out of the PHP PCRE manual...) http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: You are right.  I do want to include the / in the regular expression.  I did not know about the option to use the # as the delimiter. (learned something new today).  After further testing I found that the max-keys option was causing issue for some reason as well, so I took that out, and it all seems to be working now.  Thank you for your help.